# fetching friends info in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing an app to fetch my friends work history and education from facebook

For some of my friends

```
    graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,work&.........
```

gives details about their employers

For a friend xyz I get only the name while using the above url. But when I try

```
    graph.facebook.com/xyz?fields=name,work
```

I get his work details also.

What is the difference between these two urls?

Answer (score 1):

The first URI, `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,work`, returns information about the current logged-in user's friends. Depending on the permissions given by that user (the person using your application) to your application, you may or may not be able to get their friends' work information (or any other detail that you're requesting).

The second URI, `https://graph.facebook.com/xyz?fields=name,work`, returns information about a specific user (in your case, `xyz`). Whether or not you can do this is also dependent on if that information is public or authorized for the access token of your application I believe.

Try exploring the Facebook Graph using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Comment: I pass my access token(with permissions for friends_work) to the app and xyz is my friend, Why these two uris behave differently? I tried Graph API Explorer also, no use but

Comment: @KalyanaSundaram that might be because he might have privacy settings restricting access

Answer (score 0):

May be  your friend xyz1 have set privacy on work history,thats why you are not getting it